# Calculate Average Rating to show on press of Next Previous Button

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

If have these 2 tables:

**COMICS**:

```
Field          Type                   Comment
comic_id       bigint(10)             unsigned NOT NULL
comic_title    varchar(500)           NULL
```

**RATING**

```
Field               Type               Comment
rating_id           bigint(10)         unsigned NOT NULL
comic_id            varchar(250)       NULL
rating              varchar(250)       NULL
```

Now I want to create an API to return Top rated Comics on Press of `Next` & `Previous` Button on behalf of rating.

1. By default the API return top rated Comic. Then on Press of next button How should i calculate the Lowest avg rating comic
2. Same goes here how will i calculate the Highest Avg Rating of a comic on press of Back button.

In short i want to create a `Next previous Button that will show avg rating from rating table on behalf of comic id`.

Comment: Please explain yourself properly. This is a very confusing question

Comment: Sounds good. Go ahead and come back here when you get stuck somewhere

Comment: SQL and buttons don't make much sense in one question

Comment: @UmairAkhtar Are these table schema new or existing? I think I get your question

Comment: Ok let me show you the Schema here:  And sorry for such confusing questions i am newbie..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something for you to start with, although most probably your question will be closed....The sample is based on a usual scenario since there's no much info we can grab to help you out from your question...

Here is a tip on [How to post a question on SO](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx).

*** [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cfe8c/7)**

Samples to try:

```
select c.comic_id, c.comic_title, 
COUNT(r.comic_id), avg(r.ratings)
from comics c
left join rating r
on r.comic_id = c.comic_id
group by c.comic_id
;

| COMIC_ID | COMIC_TITLE | COUNT(R.COMIC_ID) | AVG(R.RATINGS) |
---------------------------------------------------------------
|      100 |           a |                 3 |              5 |
|      200 |           b |                 4 |            6.5 |
|      300 |           c |                 3 |         5.6667 |
|      400 |           d |                 2 |              8 |
```

min average:

```
select x.comic_id, x.comic_title,
min(average) from (
select c.comic_id, c.comic_title, 
COUNT(r.comic_id), avg(r.ratings) average
from comics c
left join rating r
on r.comic_id = c.comic_id
group by c.comic_id) x
;

| COMIC_ID | COMIC_TITLE | MIN(AVERAGE) |
-----------------------------------------
|      100 |           a |            5 |
```

EDIT AS PER OP'S COMMENTS:

OP wants to rank the Lowest rating, second lowest and so on.. Highest rating, second highest.. etc

This query will use a `variable` to rank.

*** [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cfe8c/11)**

Query:

```
select x.comic_id, x.comic_title,
x.average from (
select (@rank:=@rank+1) as rank, c.comic_id, c.comic_title, 
COUNT(r.comic_id), avg(r.ratings) average
from (select @rank:=0) rk, comics c
left join 
rating r
on r.comic_id = c.comic_id
group by c.comic_id
order by average asc) x
where x.rank = 1
;

| COMIC_ID | COMIC_TITLE | AVERAGE |
------------------------------------
|      100 |           a |       5 |
```

> In order to get familiar with JOIN, you may take a look at this article: [VISUAL REPRESENTATION OF SQL JOINS](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

[image]

Comment: What if i want to take out next lowest rating of comic_id? & What if i want to take out previous highest rating of comic_id?

Comment: @UmairAkhtar Do you want to rank them for lowest, next lowest and so on? same goes for highest as well? =)

Comment: What if the comic_id has no record in the comic_rating table ??? i wanted to show those comic records as well with 0 rating

Comment: When you are using a `left join` on the `comics` table, it will take all the `comics id` from that table. I am updating the answer now for ranking.

Comment: You can use `Coalesce(col,0)` to show `0` when a column would return null to a zero, in your case if a comic id has no ratings..

Comment: [Here is the link for you try out for `left join` showing `0` when no rating and with any ranking of your choice to pull the lowest, second lowest, thrid highest... etc... records..](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3e33/12)

Comment: ok Thanks... Now one last question..

Comment: ok Thanks... i got now how to show 0 instead on NULL, now one last question:   What if i enter a where clause in the query WHERE rat <= 6 its not showing the records that are with 0 ratings.

Comment: Sorry I am not following you.. what do you mean by `rat <= 6`? What results do you want to get? The ranking is done based on the average. What is `rat`? `DO YOU WANT TO SHOW RECORDS WITH 0 AVERAGE RATING?`

Comment: In that case you don't need any ranking, you can use the first link that I have given for demo and add a `having clause`. e.g. Select id, title, avg(rating) as average from... group by id having average <= 0` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cfe8c/12

Answer (score 0):

Create a view to make it easier: (update to include comic with no rating)

```
CREATE VIEW avg_comic_rating AS 
SELECT 
    comics.comic_id, comics.comic_title, COALESCE(AVG(comic_rating), 0.0)AS avg_rating
 FROM
    comics LEFT JOIN comic_rating
ON   (comics.comic_id = comic_rating.comic_id)
GROUP BY comics.comic_id;
```

Then use Limit offsets for pagination as:

```
select * from avg_comic_rating order by avg_rating desc, comic_title asc limit 0,2;
+----------+-------------+------------+
| comic_id | comic_title | avg_rating |
+----------+-------------+------------+
|        6 | zorro       |     7.5000 |
|        5 | super man   |     7.0000 |
+----------+-------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.05 sec)


select * from avg_comic_rating order by avg_rating desc, comic_title asc limit 2,2;
+----------+-------------+------------+
| comic_id | comic_title | avg_rating |
+----------+-------------+------------+
|        4 | cat woman   |     4.5000 |
|        2 | he man      |     4.5000 |
+----------+-------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Table contents for reference:

```
select * from comics;
+----------+-------------+
| comic_id | comic_title |
+----------+-------------+
|        1 | batman      |
|        2 | he man      |
|        3 | she man     |
|        4 | cat woman   |
|        5 | super man   |
|        6 | zorro       |
+----------+-------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

select * from comic_rating;
+-----------+----------+--------------+
| rating_id | comic_id | comic_rating |
+-----------+----------+--------------+
|         1 |        1 |            2 |
|         2 |        2 |            3 |
|         3 |        3 |            1 |
|         4 |        4 |            4 |
|         5 |        5 |            6 |
|         6 |        6 |            5 |
|         7 |        1 |            5 |
|         8 |        2 |            6 |
|         9 |        3 |            7 |
|        10 |        4 |            5 |
|        11 |        5 |            8 |
|        12 |        6 |           10 |
+-----------+----------+--------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)

select * from avg_comic_rating;
+----------+-------------+------------+
| comic_id | comic_title | avg_rating |
+----------+-------------+------------+
|        1 | batman      |     3.5000 |
|        2 | he man      |     4.5000 |
|        3 | she man     |     4.0000 |
|        4 | cat woman   |     4.5000 |
|        5 | super man   |     7.0000 |
|        6 | zorro       |     7.5000 |
+----------+-------------+------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Great Thanks.. I have a Question here:  What if the comic_id has no record in the comic_rating table ??? i wanted to show those comic records as well with 0 rating

Comment: @UmairAkhtar Nice catch; in that you need to change the view creation statement. Modified the DDL in the post.